# AWS: How to launch multiple of the same instance from python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS Windows Server 2016 VM. This VM has a bunch of libraries/software installed (dependencies).

I'd like to, using python3, launch and deploy multiple clones of this instance. I want to do this so that I can use them almost like batch compute nodes in Azure.

I am not very familiar with AWS, but I did find this [tutorial](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-create-an-ec2-instance-with-python).
Unfortunately, it shows how to launch an instance from the store, not an existing configured one.

How would I do what I want to achieve? Should I create an `AMI` from my configured VM and then just launch that?

Any up-to-date links and/or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create an AMI from the running instance, then launch N instances from that AMI. You can do both using the AWS console or you could call boto3 [create_image()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.create_image) and [run_instances()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances). Alternatively, look at [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image.html) for creating AMIs.

You don't strictly need to create an AMI. You could simply the bootstrap each instance as it launches via a [user data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) or some form of CM like Ansible.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to do things like, once the instance has launched, copy over files and execute them?

Comment: Yes, you can download and run scripts at launch time through userdata, or you can do the same thing later using any of the methods that you would normally use on a server that you own or on a VM that you use. What will be different is getting access to the EC2 instance. You need to understand basic VPC/EC2 constructs like Security Groups (firewalls). Recommend a YouTube search for "ec2 basic launch instance" and watch the first couple of videos.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.